# Xcode lock view to bouncing navigation bar

Tags: xcode, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, nslayoutconstraint, large-title

[image: animation]

## Situation

I have a `UIView` that has a layout constraint to the bottom of the safe area. This is inside a `UIViewController` inside a `UINavigationController`. It works fine when the navigation bar is in-between the large title and the "regular" title. However when bouncing lower the `UINavigationBar` covers the custom view.

## Question

How can I lock the position of a custom view to the bottom of a **bouncing** NavigationBar. Storyboard solution would be optimal, Swift solution would be sufficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add `menuView` in `navigationBar`

```
let menuView = UIView()
menuView.backgroundColor = .red
menuView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

self.navigationController?.navigationBar.addSubview(menuView)

[menuView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: (self.navigationController?.navigationBar.leadingAnchor)!),
menuView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: (self.navigationController?.navigationBar.bottomAnchor)!),
menuView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: (self.navigationController?.navigationBar.trailingAnchor)!),
menuView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60)].forEach{ $0.isActive = true }
```

**Result**

[image]

> But you have to maintain contentInset of
>   UITableView/UICollectionView/UIScrollView & Scroll indicator

**Suggestions**

Use Section Header of TableView/CollectinView in this type of situation.

Comment: Is there any way of achieving this in a storyboard?